# Implement XOR with minimal AND/OR gates

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I was wondering if there was some specific method to finding the circuit for an xor with a variety of variables. Like, I can easily expand a set number of xor(2 inputs) and xor(3 inputs) but there has to be some way to minimize the number you use. So, say XOR of 17 variables, how would you minimally expand it, using the least number of and/or gates?

Thank you

Comment: You can't make XOR gates out of just ANDs and ORs.  You will need some inverters (NOT gates) also.

Comment: 4 diodes in a bridge = XOR diode logic. this is the minimum. XOR=AB + A!B!

Comment: What do you mean as in variables?

Comment: @Bradman175 I think he means "inputs": "a variety of variables" -> "a given number of inputs".

Comment: This is not easy.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I don't see how a bridge rectifier is a XOR gate... Oh nvm. Not a true XOR though.

Comment: Yeah, im sorry. I mean't inputs.

Comment: Sorry I was too quick Diode Bridge for AC in and DC pulse out and XOR logic is not AB+A!B!   , this is XNOR , rather XOR function is AB!+A!B (0nly one input exclusive high while other low) This you can reduce with AND OR INV or NAND NOR INV gates using DeMorgan's rule to decide which is minimum. For internal structures , NAND is simpler than AND.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqRHP6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a popular circuit to implement the XOR gate with minimal number of basic universal gates.

Take two inputs at a time and implement many such circuits, then take their outputs and send them into the same XOR circuit two at a time. Something like the draw of a knockout style tournament. Your final output will be the XOR of all your inputs.

### [image]